HttpPost, [FromForm] and binding collection doesn't work
I am using Asp.Net Core 8.
I have the following:
  public class EventIdsWrapper
  {
    public int[] EventIds { get; set; }
  }

in the web api controller:
   [Route("transfersLog"), HttpPost()]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetTransfersLog([FromForm] EventIdsWrapper eventIds)
   {
     var data = await SomeService.GetTransfersLogs(eventIds, db);

     var result = new 
     {
       data = data,
       total = data.Count
     };

     return Ok(result);
   }

Here is what gets sent from the browser:

EventIds=1246501&EventIds=1375324&EventIds=1380287&EventIds=1738599&EventIds=1741915&EventIds=1743859&page=1&start=0&limit=25

The content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8.
The issue is that eventIds.EventIds is null. Why is it not populated? What am I missing? According to the docs this should work. They gave this as an example: selectedCourses=1050&selectedCourses=2000.
Side note, this code worked in Asp.Net Mvc 5.* (with [FromBody] instead of [FromForm]).
Update:
This variant works, where I bind the array parameter directly to the form data:
   [Route("transfersLog"), HttpPost()]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetTransfersLog([FromForm] int[] EventIds)
   {
     var data = await SomeService.GetTransfersLogs(eventIds, db);

     var result = new 
     {
       data = data,
       total = data.Count
     };

     return Ok(result);
   }

I am still curious why the other option doesn't work though. There are other cases that have more data in the forms. Does it mean the arrays have to be separated from the rest of the form in order to be able to bind them successfully?
TIA

i think a form really is considered binding to a "dictionary", and an array is not a key-value pair

In fact it is a well-known attribute in asp.net core that the model name better not the same with property name.
As you can see in the log, when the model is [FromForm] EventIdsWrapper eventIds, the property is not correctly bound as your payload contains only the property name. Some default process has executed according to the document you mentioned.

While the model is [FromForm] EventIdsWrapper xxx, the property got bound correctly.

In a word, change your parameter name eventIds to be different with the property name EventIds and it will work.


That was it!
